# Query to always return a fix number of rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I can write a query to return top 5 products in a product category basis their sales figure. However in cases when lets say a Product category has only 2 products then only 2 rows are returned.

Is there a way to insert dummy rows such that the 5 rows are always returned per product category. The dummy rows just need to have the  right product category and null values for remaining columns.

Comment: The last sentence of your question seems to contradict what you said earlier.  Do you want _five_ products per category, always, or do you want _five_ records in your result set?  Sample data and expected output would really help here.

Comment: So what would those 3 extra rows contain. Presumably nothing. Perhaps if you told us why completely empty rows are required another solution may present itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION ALL` to add extra rows and then filter to only keep 5

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT col1, col2
  FROM   your_table
  WHERE  ROWNUM <= 5
UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL, NULL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5
-- ORDER BY col1 NULLS LAST, col2 NULLS LAST -- If necessary
)
WHERE  ROWNUM <= 5
```

Or if you are doing it for multiple groups:

```
WITH categories ( category, col1, rn ) AS (
  SELECT category,
         col1,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY category ORDER BY col1 )
  FROM   products
)
SELECT category,
       col1
FROM   (
  SELECT category,
         col1,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY category ORDER BY rn ) AS rn
  FROM   (
    SELECT category,
           col1,
           rn
    FROM   categories
    WHERE  rn <= 5
  )
  UNION ALL
  (
     SELECT category,
            NULL,
            5 + LEVEL
     FROM   categories
     WHERE  rn = 1
     CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5
  )
)
WHERE  rn <= 5;
```